# How to pass id with ajax from one form to another?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii2

Yii2. I have two forms:

[**First**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDSjv.jpg) -  `site.com/test1/form1`

when I choose `Test1`, Ajax loads the data from the database in `Test2` and `Test3`

But I need to load the data into a second form. I select `Test1` in `Form1`, then I'm creating this form. After that I go to create `Form2`, and when form opens I see the downloaded data.

[**That's how it should be**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UgCT.jpg)

StreetsController.php for data:

```
 public function actionGetNM($id)
{

    $street = Streets::findOne($id);
    echo Json::encode($street);
}
```

In _form1:

```
 $script = <<< JS
$('#form1-test1').change(function(){
    var id = $(this).val();

    $.get('/streets/get-n-m',{ id : id },function(data){
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);
        $('#form1-test2').attr('value',data.n);
        $('#form2-test3').attr('value',data.m);
    });
});

JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
```

I think that after creation `Form1` need to get `id` `form1`and transmit on `form2`, where Ajax gets data from Json. It's all in theory, I don't understand how to implement it. Can anyone help?

Comment: So, from what you have done, it's not working? Do you have errors in your console?

Comment: this  works perfect, but on one page, in one form.But it doesn't transmit values from one form to another, I think doesn't accept `id` Test1. Logic is:  create a `_form`(form1/create)-> fill data->choose `Test1`(for ex.)-> save. Then pass on to another menu item to create a `_form`(form2/create), and I see in the cells `Test2.2` and `Test3.3` are transferred from the value of the `form1`

Comment: by the adress ".../streets/get-n-m?id=1"(id=2; id=3 etc.) have Json massive. So I think need to get id from dropdownlist select from `form1` to `form2`. Don't understand how to do it.